# Missing OpenTK when porting Xamarin.iOS app to .Net 7

Tags: xamarin.ios, opentk, net-7.0-ios

I am porting a `Xamarin.iOS` application using OpenTK to `net7.0-ios`:

> error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'OpenTK' could not be found
> (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

OpenTK assembly seems to be missing from `net7.0-ios`.

In `net7.0-android` one can reference the [Xamarin.Legacy.OpenTK](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Legacy.OpenTK/) NuGet package to get OpenTK. But this package is only for Android. I cannot find the corresponding legacy package for iOS.

Are legacy bindings for OpenTK no longer available in `net7.0-ios`?

Answer (score 0):

I think OpenTK only supports

- .Net 3.x
- .Net 4.x
- .Net 5.x

I am currently waiting too...
Source: https://opentk.net/